# How to call another function below main (VC++ C)

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to call a function below, but the IDE can't find a function if it isn't above main.
I'm using visual studio professional 2013

This works:

```
void Load()
{
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Load();
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Load();
}

void Load()
{
}
```

Comment: `Load` is a function, not a class; there is no class in your program. You can't call a function unless a declaration of that function is visible. This is a C and C++ rule, not specific to Visual Studio. And since your question is tagged "C", not "C++", there's no such thing as a "class" anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You have to have a function declaration above `main` if you want achieve this.

```
 void Load();

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
      Load();
 }

 void Load()
 {

 }
```

Comment: `void Load()` is a *declaration*, not a *definition* (I've corrected your answer).

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks. I realized as soon as I saw the notification button turn red.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare your method before your `main()` so that the compiler knows it exists. It's the basis of Header files.

```
void Load();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
      Load();
 }

void Load()
 {
 }
```